# How to find the last output cell of the group to which a certain cell belongs?

Tags: notebooks, cells

Simple question, but I cannot find an answer in the documentation.

I have a `CellObject` handle of some cell in some notebook. This cell has "Subsubsection" style, so it starts a new cell group. Inside this cell group there are one or more input, output and text cell with different styles. I want to get the `CellObject` handle of the *last* output cell in this group. With this handle I can get the content of the cell and do whatever I need.

I don't want to change the selection on the notebook or change and restore the selection or give any visual interference from what I'm doing.

The notebook is long and complex with a lot of graphics; the access to the group and last cell should be resonably fast.

It is possible?

---

To make things clear I want to implement a function with this signature:

```
lastOutputOfGroup[cellObject_CellObject] := ...
```

that, given a notebook, *for example*

```
nb = CreateDocument[{
    TextCell["Section", "Section"],
    TextCell["Subsection", "Subsection"],
    TextCell["Subsubsection 1", "Subsubsection"],
    TextCell["1+1", "Input"],
    TextCell["Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2\[Pi]}]", "Input"],
    TextCell["Subsubsection 2", "Subsubsection"],
    TextCell["Expand[(1+x)^5]", "Input"],
    TextCell["Plot[Cos[x],{x,0,2\[Pi]}]", "Input"]
    }];
NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> True];
```

and and handle to some heading cell, *for example*

```
cellObject = First@Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Subsubsection"]
```

returns the `CellObject` of the cell containing the `Sin[x]` plot so that I can acquire its `Graphics` expression.

To make things even clear I added, as temporary answer, a slow method I found after posting the question. An efficient version of my implementation is what I'm searching for.

Sorry, I don't know how to rephrase this question to make it less vague.

Comment: `SelectionMove` is a generic approach, could you explain why it is not acceptable? You can always use `AutoScroll->False` option.

Comment: @Kuba I'm not 100% sure that `SelectionMove` will cause any real problem to me, but, because I go to use this routine in some kind of "background" processing of my notebook, maybe "long", I don't find "clean" to act on UI during this process. These repeating `SelectionMove` maybe can interfere with what I'm doing interactively?

Comment: If you are not using the notebook that is being searched then I don't think it will cause any problems.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Why do you state my requirements are changing?  I still want to get the `CellObject` handle of the last output cell of `CellGroup` started by a given `CellObject` handle, without changing the UI...

Comment: okay I'll reverse my close vote (if that is possible) but I find the question too vague to attempt to answer

Comment: @Kuba So if I use the `SelectionMove` method I cannot for example edit anything of the notebook processed?

Answer (score 1):

I found this method.

```
lastOutputOfGroup[cellObject_CellObject] :=
 With[{groupCells = Cases[NotebookGet@Notebooks[cellObject], 
     CellGroupData[cells : {NotebookRead@cellObject, ___}, ___] :> 
      cells, \[Infinity]]},
  ToExpression@First@Last@Cases[groupCells, Cell[_, "Output", ___], \[Infinity]]
  ]
```

that apparently works:

```
lastOutputOfGroup[cellObject]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is it a good way? Are there drawbacks? For example, what I need to put in my pattern? `CellGroup` or `CellGroupData`? I don't understand the difference.

One problem is that my method in the real case is very slow: the slowest part are the `NotebookGet` and the first `Cases` (i.e. acquiring the notebook expression and to find the cell in the large notebook).

Comment: So you have to evaluate that from within a cell group??

Comment: And where do you want the output of that function to appear. It seems like it will have to appear in the target cell group

Comment: So you want to export the last output cell of a section grouping? If that is correct you really should be saying that in the question and not leave it to guesswork. So how do you select which section grouping you want to apply this to?